# Bash. Why "while" statement with incorrect condition works?

Tags: bash, while-loop, syntax

```
while ['qwe'='rty']
do
echo yes
done
```

The condition is obviously incorrect, yet terminal is printing "yes" indefinitely.
Why is that happening?

Comment: `[qwe=rty]: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

> The condition is obviously incorrect ...

No, it really *isn't*<sup>(1)</sup>.

Spaces are required in the conditional (*including* "command" spaces separating the `[` and `]` characters from the condition by the way<sup>(2)</sup>) for `bash` to interpret the condition as a three-part test.

What you have provided (assuming your missing command spaces described above are a simple typo) is treated as a one-part test which is true so long as it is not an empty string.

You can see the difference below:

```sh
pax> [ 'abc' = 'xyz' ] && echo yes

pax> [ 'abc' = 'xyz' ] || echo no
no

pax> [ 'abc'='xyz' ] && echo yes
yes
```

The relevant section of the `bash` man-page has this (note the *spaces* in the equality checks, they're not just for separating tokens in the man-page itself):

> `string`
> `-n string`
>
> True if the length of string is non-zero.
>
> `string1 == string2`
> `string1 = string2`
>
> True if the strings are equal.  `=` should be used with the `test` command for POSIX conformance.

In other words, what you *should* have as the `while` statement is:

```sh
while [ 'qwe' = 'rty' ]
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Well, technically, it *is* incorrect, but not in the sense you mean (false). Instead, it's incorrect in the sense that it's not the expression you *think* it is :-)

---

<sup>(2)</sup> Without those command spaces, you'll see a syntax error along the lines of:

```sh
pax> ['abc' = 'xyz'] && echo yes
[abc: command not found

pax> ['abc'='xyz'] && echo yes
[abc=xyz]: command not found
```

Unless, of course, you actually *have* an executable target called `[abc=xyz]` in which case it will be executed and the return value will decide what action is taken. This is an unlikely executable target to have but it *is* possible:

```sh
pax> echo true > '[abc=xyx]' ; PATH=$PATH:.

pax> ['abc'='xyx'] && echo yes
yes
```